# Pure JS add class to only one of recurring elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to toggle a div's class in pure javascript (unfortunately I cannot use jQuery). I've got some code working but it doesn't work for multiple instances of the div and I'd appreciate some help for that.

I can't give each element it's own specific ID, so I'd need a way to target only the div with a class of 'truncate' that is the parent of the particular button that is clicked. Currently I have hidden the results by default and am just toggling the 'show' class

```
<div class="truncate">
  <div class="result">Result 1</div>
  <div class="result">Result 2</div>
  <div id="button">Show more</div>
</div>
```

```
collapse= document.getElementById('button');

collapse.onclick = function() {
  collapse.parentElement.classList.toggle("show");
};
```

```
/* HIDE PLATES BY DEFAULT */
.truncate .result {
  display: none;
}
/* SHOW RESULTS WHEN SHOW CLASS APPLIED */
.truncate.show .result {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Thank you - help appreciated as always.

Comment: You can't re-use an id value more than once on a page, so you'll have to set up the event handler differently.

Comment: Thanks. I tried getElementByClassName by it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse (loop over) all of your `div.truncate` elements and give themselves their own functionality via the `Accordionize` Function.

```js
const Accordionize = el => {
  const results = el.querySelectorAll('.result')
  const toggleButton = el.querySelector('button')
  let open = false
  
  const _toggle = () => {
    const action = open ? 'remove' : 'add'
    
    results.forEach(item => item.classList[action]('show'))
    open = !open
  }
  
  toggleButton.addEventListener('click', _toggle)
}

// get all div.truncate and apply them to their own instance of Accordionize
document.querySelectorAll('.truncate').forEach(Accordionize)
```

```css
.truncate {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5
}
.result {
  display: none;
}
.show {
 display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="truncate">
  <div class="result">Result 1</div>
  <div class="result">Result 2</div>
  <button>Show more1</button>
</div>
<div class="truncate">
  <div class="result">Result 3</div>
  <div class="result">Result 4</div>
  <button>Show more2</button>
</div>
<div class="truncate">
  <div class="result">Result 5</div>
  <div class="result">Result 6</div>
  <button>Show more3</button>
</div>
<div class="truncate">
  <div class="result">Result 7</div>
  <div class="result">Result 8</div>
  <button>Show more4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oo fancy - need to learn more about this, but works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need getElementsByClassName

```js
(function() {
    var collapse = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
    for (var elIndex = 0; elIndex < collapse.length; elIndex++) {
        collapse[elIndex].onclick = function() {
          this.parentElement.classList.toggle("show");
        };
    }
})();
```

```css
/* HIDE PLATES BY DEFAULT */
.truncate .result {
  display: none;
}
/* SHOW RESULTS WHEN SHOW CLASS APPLIED */
.truncate.show .result {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="truncate">
  <div class="result">Result 1</div>
  <div class="result">Result 2</div>
  <div class="button">Show more</div>
</div>

<div class="truncate">
  <div class="result">Result 1</div>
  <div class="result">Result 2</div>
  <div class="button">Show more</div>
</div>

<div class="truncate">
  <div class="result">Result 1</div>
  <div class="result">Result 2</div>
  <div class="button">Show more</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah elements plural! Thanks so much - every day's a school day!

Comment: It's now working using the 'getElementsByClassName' but 'parentElement' seems to be targeting the most top level div, whereas I just want to target the first one above that it's nesting in. Is there a way to target just one level up or target the nearest div with a certain class?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the id of Show more to class.
And use the following code.

```
collapse =document.getElementsByClassName('button');
for(let i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++){
  let oneElement = collapse[i];
  oneElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
   oneElement.parentElement.classList.toggle("show");
  })
}
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns element collection and it's iterable. You can use ```for of``` loop.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of element being plural.